# Java: get all method parameters as Object array

Tags: java, syntax, method-parameters

Is it possible to do this:

```
void foo(Bar b, FooBar fb){
    Object[] args=getArgs() //Contains the parameters b & fb
}
```

And if yes, how?

(I dont know the name and the number of parameters)

Comment: `Object[] args = new Object[] {b, fb};` Why?

Comment: Or more direct: `Object[] args = { b, fb };`.

Comment: I dont know the name and the number of arguments(Sorry for beeing unclear)

Comment: Yes you do know the name and number of arguments: Two arguments `b` and `fb`.

Comment: Of course you know the names of the _parameters_. They're declared right above.

Comment: Above ways are straightforward. If, on the other hand, you are looking for an `arguments` object a-la JavaScript, then no, we don't have access to such an object in Java.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to pass any number of arguments to method you can use varargs like `void foo(Object... args)`. Since `args` will be `Object[]` array you can access them via `args[0]` and so on.

Comment: I have no idea in what situation you wouldn't know the parameters...

Answer (score 5):

No, Java does not support a simple, generic way to pack all the method arguments into an array. This is pretty standard for statically typed programming languages. It's generally dynamic languages like JavaScript and shell scripting languages that do allow retrieving all the arguments as an array.

Answer (score 4):

Given a method like you declare it, there is no (easy/standard) way to retrieve it as an `Object[]`.

Now, you can always declare a method as

```
public void doSomething(Object... args) {
   Object o1 = args[0];  // etc
}
```

then you can call

```
doSomething(foo);
// or
doSomething(foo, bar, baz);
```

but you lose all type safety doing it this way; I don't really recommend it.